# How to send a JSON array in multipart/form-data in Swagger UI?

Tags: multipartform-data, swagger-ui, openapi

I’m trying to send an array of objects through `multipart/form-data`:

```yaml
post:
      summary: Creates a user
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties: # Request parts
                id:
                  type: string
                  format: uuid
                address:      # <---------
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      street:
                        type: string
                      city:
                        type: string
                profileImage:
                  type: string
                  format: base64
```

But Swagger UI sends the `address` array incorrectly - as `{},{}` instead of `[{},{}]`, that is, without the enclosing square brackets:

[image]

I even tried encoding it separately as JSON.

What am I missing, please?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not being sent properly". What result do you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: The array angle brackets are being removed. That is, this "{},{}" is being sent instead of this "[{},{}]"

Comment: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-rQkTpWXjMeMO1ujj_EeWmKQLNs_7NDC/view?usp=sharing) is the result image

Comment: [It's a bug in Swagger UI.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68291856/113116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i later got it to work by adding example

```
post:
      summary: Creates a user
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties: # Request parts
                id:
                  type: string
                  format: uuid
                address:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      street:
                        type: string
                      city:
                        type: string
                    example:
                      - street: Jones Street, Manhattan
                        city: New York
                      - street: Hollywood Boulevard
                        city: Los Angeles
                profileImage:
                  type: string
                  format: base64
```

my observation is just send or modify what you already have in the example, adding new ones won't be correctly formatted. that is, if you have two items in an array work with those two do not add extra items